# Burning Rubber Smell From Drill Press Belts

Tags: drill, maintenance

After 20+ years my drill press finally ate a belt. Before the belt failed there was a burning rubber smell. Now after replacing both belts, the smell is still there.

I don't see anything obvious and the pulley alignment seems reasonable. Could this be a normal "break in" smell or is something wrong?

Comment: A worn belt will crack and get loose.  Not sure why it would burn or overheat.  With the belt take off, the drill spindle should turn freely - does it?  If it seems ok, burning rubber smell can linger for a while.

Comment: I think the burning smell may have been due to slipping.

Answer (score 2):

A burning rubber smell comes from friction between the belt and something else. A well adjusted belt should not smell on break in.

Possibilities:

- Belt rubbing on a pulley that's out of alignment (probably not since it's been checked)
- Belt rubbing on rubber left behind from the previous belt (clean the pulleys)
- Belt slipping (check and adjust tension if needed. As JPhi1618 said - check to make sure spindles are turning freely.)
- Belt rubbing on something in the path of the belt (check for a clear belt path)

Be careful, things can break and fires can start when there is unwanted friction.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a "break-in" smell, it's more likely a residual smell stirred up by the air movement now that it is running again. Once a belt burns, that burned rubber smell permeates everything, even the paint. If you have double checked everything as previously suggested and find no evidence of new problems, I would run it for a while and see if the smell dissipates. It takes time.